# Heuristics-based vs behavioral malware detection

Tags: antivirus, detection

I'm working on my thesis and I have a couple questions about differences between heuristics-based and behavioral malware detection.

Does heuristics-based detection rely only on statically examining malcode in order to find some kinds of instructions? Or maybe the anti-virus application has its own sandbox which can execute malicious code?

Is behavioral detection, which observes how the program is executed, done in a virtual machine like VirtualBox, or VMWare or is it done on a real machine?

I'm a little be confused because [this](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/tip/How-antivirus-software-works-Virus-detection-techniques) article states that during Heuristics-based detection the program is emulated. What exactly does that mean? Does it mean what's I said above - that the AV app has its own, basic virtual machine?

Comment: Virtual machines do not have to be a full VM. The term you are looking for is "sandbox".

Comment: The article says: "emulate running the file" not that "the program is emulated".